# How make lambda where on list of list?

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have two classes:

```
public class firstClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<secondClass> Elements { get; set; }
}

public class secondClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Is{ get; set; }
}
```

and using of their:

```
List<firstClass> list = allFirstClassFromDB.Include("Elements");
```

and then my list contain for example:

```
list[0] - {Id : 1, Elements : [0] { Id: 1, Is: true }, [1] { Id: 2, Is: true }, [2] { Id: 3, Is: false }
list[1] - {Id : 2, Elements : [0] { Id:4, Is: false }, [1] { Id: 5, Is: true }, [2] { Id: 6, Is: false }
list[2] - {Id : 3, Elements : [0] { Id:7, Is: false } }
```

So The result which I need is only this location which contain `Elements` which have `Is` prop set for true, sth like this:

```
list[0] - {Id : 1, Elements : [0] { Id: 1, Is: true }, [1] { Id: 2, Is: true } }
list[1] - {Id : 2, Elements : [0] { Id: 5, Is: true } }
```

It is possible in linq? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using LINQ:

```
var filteredList = list
  .Select(
    x => new firstClass {
      Id = x.Id,
      Elements = x.Elements.Where(y => y.Is).ToList()
    }
  )
  .Where(x => x.Elements.Count > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of `firstClass` which does not have any `secondClass.Is` `true` by `Where` clause, then re-build `firstClass` just to filter all `secondClass.Is` true

```
list.Where(f => f.Elements.Any(s => s.Is))
    .Select(f => new firstClass() {
                                      Id = f.Id,
                                      Elements = f.Elements.Where(s => s.Is)
                                                           .ToList()
    }).ToList();
```